# consistency of an estimator in real data

Tags: probability, sampling, conditional-probability, sample-size

as we know in statistics we are interested in the properties of an estimator , as my estimator is consistent , in probability sense it can be shown as $P(|estimator - true| <- positive) = 1$ as interpretation is we increase sample size probability approaches 1 well.

But i'm in confusion since a long time what is a practical example of this equation ,. give me any real example how it approaches to 1 or what is statement actually saying, data example will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A practical example would be great but it's difficult to come by unless we know the "true" relationship between our features and what we are trying to predict. This isn't always the case, maybe you could find some data in physics where a known relationship is present and we are trying to estimate the parameters. Anyway, this illustrative example is with some dummy data.

First lets assume a true relationship of

$$y = mx+c+n(0,\sigma)$$
$$y = 3x+5+n(0,2)$$

We then try to estimate this relationship given varying amounts of data. Here is the code to reproduce this example in R.

```
set.seed(42)

n_sample = 20

data = data.frame(x = seq(1,n_sample))

# y = 3x+5 + noise
data[['y']] = 3*data[['x']] + 5 + rnorm(n_sample,0,2)

fit = lm(y~x, data = data)

summary(fit)
```

For an `n_sample` of 20 out estimators are

- intercept = 7.03
- m = 2.84

however for `n_sample = 10000`

- intercept = 4.976
- m = 3.00

hence, as `n_sample` increases indefinitely our estimate converges to the true value.

Comment: if i just use P(|estimator−true| > positive) it approaches 0 im confused in ( 0 and 1)

Comment: plz sir answer about o and 1 what does it mean , i will wait